# Possibly faulty ram slot

Tags: windows, laptop, memory

I recently bought an extra 8 gigs of RAM for my laptop (HP Pavilion Gaming - 15-ec0013dx). After installing it the computer recognizes the RAM, but will not apply it as usable.

Some of the stuff I've tried:

- reseating the ram, half a trillion times
- making sure that Windows isn't limiting the ram inside the boot tab of msconfig
- updated everything including bios and even went as far as upgrading to windows 11 in hopes it would fix it
- edited my system registry to try to get it to use the RAM.

My best resulting experiment was switching out the original RAM stick with the new one. The computer works fine, but when I use the old ram stick in the slot I'm using for the new ram stick the computer won't even post. I looked over the pins very carefully and wasn't able to see any damage, I used some compressed air to no avail.

**Anyone has any idea how I might fix this issue?**

Edit: to clarify, my computer has 2 ram slots, one that has the old ramstick that i've had since i got the computer, and an empty one i'm trying to use a new ramstick in.
when i put the old ramstick that i know is good into the unused slot, the computer will not post, but the computer will boot if i put either ramstick in place of the old one. ps, i always ground myself and am very careful when inserting parts, i love my computer like you wouldn't believe.

Computer info page:
[image: computer info page].

Comment: "*reseating the ram, half a trillion times*" -- That probably broke the socket(s) and/or contaminated it.  See https://engineering.purdue.edu/MSE/news/2015/20142015-industry-sponsored-senior-designed-posters/Cisco%20First%20Insertion%20Failure%20of%20Dual%20In-Line%20Memory%20Modules.pdf  FYI compressed air does not remove oil.

Comment: Especially when you're handling memory while not grounded!

Comment: What memory did you buy? Was it from somewhere reputable?

Comment: “The computer works fine, but when I use the old ram stick in the slot I'm using for the new ram stick the computer won't even post.” - What? Can you explain this better by editing your question?